# Finding average value via an integral equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The function $u(x)$ is a solution of the second-order ODE

$$\alpha\frac{d^2u}{{dx}^2}+ru(1-u)-u = 0 $$

satisfying the boundary conditions $$\frac{du}{dx}\Bigg|_{x=0,L}=0$$

and is bounded in $0 < u(x) < 1$

I'm hoping to find a closed form for the average value of $u(x)$ over the domain $[0,L]$:

$$\bar u = \int_0^Lu(x)dx$$

I've reduced this to

$$\int_0^Lu(x)dx = \frac{r}{r-1}\int_0^Lu(x)^2dx$$

for some parameter $r$, and I'm unclear on where to go from here. I'd like to find a closed form for $\bar u$.

If this is intractable, is there a way to asymptotically expand this average value as $\dfrac{r}{r-1}\to\infty$?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking or where you got the above formulae from.

Comment: Sorry, edited. I'm looking for a closed form for $\int_0^Lu(x)dx$.

Comment: Another thing: if $0 < u < 1$ then $\alpha u'' = -ru(1-u)-u < 0$ so $u'$ is increasing or decreasing on the whole of $[0,1]$ depending on $\alpha$ so the BC $u'=0$ at $x=L$ can never be satisfied unless $ru(1-u) + u \equiv 0$ so $u = \frac{1+r}{r}$ or $u = 0$. But none of these satisfy $0 < u < 1$... (this assumes $r>0$)

Comment: Ah yes, there is a typo. The correct PDE is $0=\alpha\frac{d^2u}{{dx}^2}+ru(1-u)-u$, which I believe remedies both those concerns.

Comment: Are you sure about this for the solution: $0<u(x)<1$?

Comment: The equation is not a PDE (partial differential equation), bun an ODE (ordinary differential equation.)

Comment: There are bounded and unbounded solutions, but none among the bounded ones is into $0$ and $1$.

Comment: $u=(1-r)/r$ is a solution. If $r>1$, it satisfies $0<u<1$. However, uniqueness fails, since $u=0$ is another solution.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre You are right :) It seems a physics problem, but a not very well posed one.